# Product page on brands block

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I created pages for brands that I sell on my shop. Each product is associated with a brand taxonomy term. I created a view block that displays pages of brands. The block is displayed throughout the store and displays the entire list of brands. How to display only those brands related to product pages?

I know we need to use contextual filters, but I do not know how to configure.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the following:

- Create a new View to display the Taxonomy Terms for Brand
  [image]
- In the **Views UI**, add a new **Relationship Taxonomy term: Content with term**, and uncheck *"require this relationship"*.
- Add a new Contextual filter : **Content: Nid** and choose the just-created relationship as the relationship. Provide default value > **Content ID From URL** under When the filter value is **NOT** available.

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: hello, thank you, but it does not work, here the export of sight
 http://pastebin.com/i7Wf8yEx

Comment: hi, hmm from what i can see you have created a view that lists nodes. What you will have to create is a view that will list  taxonomy terms. See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

There are certain steps which you can follow.

1. I have created a vocabulary Brand, which contains all brand.
2. I added a field in Article Content Type, field_brand, which is term reference type.
3. After that, I create a view of type Taxonomy Term, which show terms of Brand Vocab.
4. Add Relationship for field_brand (Taxonomy term: Content using Brand).
5. Add Contextual Filter, field_brand ( Content: Brand (field_brand)), which uses above relationship.
6. Under `WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE,` Click on Radio Button `Provide Default Value`, Choose from drop down, `Taxonomy Term ID from URL`, `uncheck` checkbox `Load default filter from term page`, and `check` checkbox, `Load default filter from node page`, that's, check `Limit terms by vocabulary`, select your vocabulary, in my case it was `Brand`, under `Multiple View Handling`, check radio box, `Filter to items that share all terms`.

I have attached screenshot for the last step settings.

[image]